# Script makes bad request on its own (JS - TheMovieDb api)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, request

I'am trying to make simple web application using TMDB api but I'm having trouble with some request.
I'am successfully connecting to its api and getting all needed data and displaying it nicely. Problem is when i load my Homepage which has poster_path of movie, i get all posters nicely and displayed but in chrome dev tools I can see there is one more extra request sent (not sent by me... at least not on purpose) and its failing and wracking my app.

Chrome displays following for bad request:
GET file:///C:/Users/Ivan/Documents/testProject/fmdb-fjume-movie-database/app/%7B%7BimageBaseUrl%7D%7D/%7B%7Bmovie.poster_path%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Status: failed
Initiator: other

Here's my code for getting information and html:

Home view

```
<div class="well main-frame">
    <h1>MY MOVIE DATABASE</h1>
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-centered" style="text-align:center;" ng-repeat="movie in movies | limitTo:2">
            <img id="homeThumbnailImg" src="{{imageBaseUrl}}/{{movie.poster_path}}"></img>
            <a href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}">{{movie.original_title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('home', ['services'])
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', 'api', 'globals', function($scope, $q, api, globals) {
        $scope.imageBaseUrl = globals.getImageBaseUrl();

        $scope.getData = function() {
            $q.all([
                api.discover('movie')
            ]).then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.movies = data[0].data.results;
                    //console.log(data[0].data.results);
                },
                function(reason) {
                    console.log(reason);
                });
        }

        $scope.getData();
    }]);
```

API

```
'use strict';

angular.module('services', [])
    .constant('baseUrl', 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/')
    .constant('apiKey', 'myKey...')
    .factory('api', function($http, apiKey, baseUrl) {
        return {
            discover: function(category) {
                var url = baseUrl + 'discover/' + category + '?certification_country=US&certification.lte=G&sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=' + apiKey;
                return $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                    return data;
                });
            },

            search: function() {

            },
```

...

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your img tag to look like this:

```
<img id="homeThumbnailImg" ng-src="{{imageBaseUrl}}/{{movie.poster_path}}"></img>
```

Note the `ng-src` attribute that replaces the `src` attribute. This will prevent the browser from trying to fetch the literal string `{{imageBaseUrl}}/{{movie.poster_path}}` before angular has a chance to eval that expression.